# Is the space of all probability measures a dual space

Tags: probability, measure-theory, dual-spaces

Consider $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ a measurable space and let $P(\Sigma)$ denote the space of all probability measures on $(\Omega,\Sigma)$. I wonder if $P(\Sigma)$ can be identified with the dual space of some space $X$. If so, what is X?

It can be assumed that $\Omega$ is atmost countable.

Comment: But the space of regular signed Borel measures on $X$, of which the probability measures are a subset, is the dual space of the continuous functions with compact support on $X$, where $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. This is the [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, the "space" of probability measures is not even a vector space (not even closed under multiplication with scalars). Therefore, it cannot be a dual space of anything.